# Training with tensorflow and colab

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working on a project that involves temperature reading and LEDs. I need to train the connection between a certain temperature and the LED, but only with tensorflow and coding, not the real LED. For example, if the temperature is 37 degrees, the LED is ON and if the temperature is 39 the LED is OFF. What can I do to train this kind of connection between this variables?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to generate a csv dataset with the true value labels for the temperatures.

For example:

```
21,1
37,1
39,0
50,0
```

Then split this dataset into training and testing. A good split is 80%(training) to 20%(testing). Then use the information to train your tensorflow model which will have a single output which will either be a 1 or a 0.

Once you have trained your model to fit this data you can use the predict function to determine if the LED should be going on or off.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I don't even know how to begin the training, I'm kind of lost. Is there a link that could help me with this kind of situation? I searched videos and tried some things but i couldn't find anything that actually helped me..

Comment: @Heta, tensorflow has a steep learning curve but it is very powerful. You need to first learn about numpy and pandas if you are using python. Have a look at [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-your-first-neural-network-in-tensorflow-2-tensorflow-for-hackers-part-i-e1e2f1dfe7a0) tutorial.